# Why can't I install my Titanium project onto S2

Tags: titanium, android-install-apk

I am using Titanium SDK Version 6.0.0

So I have been able to install the project onto a 'NextBook' running Android 4.4.2
But when I try and deploy it to an S2 with 4.1.2 I get the following error

Failed to install apk on "001938f563f26e"
Error: Unknown option: -d

I am using usb debugging
the device has 1.7 GB of free space

Has anyone seen this error before ?

Thank for helping

Comment: do you have the app already installed there? Try removing it first

Comment: No, the app is not yet installed on the S2
That is the weird thing

Comment: is there enough space on the device? Is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes the device has 1.7 gb of free space and usb debugging is enabled

Comment: I think your device is not detecting properly, thats why it showing as "001938f563f26e" device otherwise it will show device name directly. may be this is the isssue

Comment: Hi VRK yes I thought the too, but I am not so sure because at the beginning cli always checks what device is attached, and it shows all the right data down to the android version installed on the device
Maybe I have to add the device somehow ? To make cli recognise it ?

Answer (score 0):

- In the manifest section of your tiapp.xml what do you have set for android:minSdkVersion? Should be 16 or higher to target that device.
- On the device, Settings -> Security, have you enabled installation from 'unknown sources'?
- If you run 'monitor' or 'monitor.exe' in a terminal, then do the install, is there any additional context surrounding the installation error that might be useful?
- If you run 'adb devices', is your device listed? Yes, your device may very well return a serial id instead of a name.
- What is your adb version? `adb --version`
- Try to install the built apk manually

`adb devices`

`adb install /path/to/your/project.apk`